# Excel VBA - Compare numbers in one column and remove the higher "neighbor" numbers

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel

I have a list of numbers in one column (0.331, 0.332, 0.444, 0.445, 0.562, 0.986, 0.990, 0.993, 1.021, 1.022, ...) and I would like to remove the numbers really close (0.001 difference only) to get the following list: (0.331, 0.444, 0.562, 0.986, 0.990, 0.993, 1.021...) removing always the higher number.

Any ideas?

The list is obviously quite long, and I already removed the duplicate.
Now, I would like to remove the higher "neighbor" numbers, maybe not the right term, but I hope you understand my question.

Thanks,

JLuc01

Comment: In the next column, take the difference then the column next to that, do an `if statement` to pull only those with difference greater than 0.001 from first column?

Comment: piggy-backing on @findwindow ...  just filter on .0001 in the next column and remove the filtered rows.... it will work perfectly as long as the data is sorted in Ascending order :)

Comment: I always forget this filter thing exist XD. (OP suggests data is in ascending order)

Comment: My data are in ascending order, but I am not sure to understand how to use the filter. At least, I think I understand the logic. I will work on that to get a VBA code with my button. Thanks.

Comment: If you had .300, .301, .302 in sequence, should .301 and .302 be deleted or just .301? If .301 is deleted first then the difference becomes .002 not .001. What if the sequence was .300, .301, .302, .303?

Comment: @JLuc01 - see [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/filter.html) for filtering. it's very easy. no need for vba - unless you need to do this over-and-over

Comment: 0.300, 0.301,0.302, 0.303,0.304,0.305 is unlikely to happen. Nevertheless, in this case, I would like the following result: 0.300,0.302,0.304.... Compare the first 2 numbers and remove the bigger one, then do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information, I finally did this bit of code which do the job.

```
' Remove close duplicate (with a difference of 0.001 only)
For i = 1 To Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value - Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i
For i = 1 To Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    If Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value < 0.002 Then
        Sheet2.Cells(i + 1, 2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Thank you for your help.

JLuc01